# Cron unterminated quoted string

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I'm implementing an automatic backup feature.
I can run this command from the command line:

```
aws ec2 create-snapshot --volume-id=vol-abc123 --description=backup$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")
```

It creates a snapshot with a description like `backup01-01-2017`

But running this command through cron like:

```
0 0 * * *    aws ec2 create-snapshot --volume-id=vol-abc123 --description=backup$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")
```

It says:

> /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

If I remove the  `$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")` from the command it works again:

```
0 0 * * *    aws ec2 create-snapshot --volume-id=vol-abc123 --description=backup
```

How can I make `$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")` to work from cron?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29578/how-can-i-execute-date-inside-of-a-cron-tab-job

Comment: Thanks for the link @jordanm. The answer to my problem was % must be escaped with \ as: `$(date +"\%d-\%m-\%Y")`.